# Does Flask support some kind of life cycle methods?

Tags: python, flask, lifecycle

Sanic framework supports [life cycle methods](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/middleware.html#listeners) such as `before_server_start`, `after_server_start`, `before_server_stop` and `after_server_stop`.

Is there something similar in Flask like this ?

I know there is a `before_request`  and `after_request`, but I'm looking for something before application is even started. I need to query a database to check if there is a certain entry in it. If there is, do some processing on that data and then run flask app.

Comment: What exactly do you need to get done during these life cycles? Then somebody may be able to tell you how to accomplish it in Flask.

Comment: I added it as a edit. But from Sanic link, they setup database. I'm looking for something similar to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at an [Application Factory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/) pattern, which would allow you to perform processing before the app object is created.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly is this the way to solve my problem, but I will try. Thank you.